# document.body.style.backgroundColor getting executed after next line

Tags: javascript, dom

my teacher is asking us a question and i couldn't find an answer:
when pressing a button on page, run those two lines:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "Green";
alert("Done");
```

why is it first alerting "Done",  and then changing the background color?
thanks.

Comment: All the currently running JS is executed before the page layout is recalculated and the page is re-rendered. It's notable, that in some browsers (ex. Fifefox) the repaint takes place before the alert box is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the alert behavior. It is triggered before page loaded.
To prevent this behavior, try alert the message asynchronnaly. Like this:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor="green";
setTimeout(alert, 50, "Done");
```

Comment: Someone explained me that even if the time-out is zero it will still work becouse the 'setTimeout' gets excuted last. i checked it, and she was right, it works also like that:

document.body.style.backgroundColor="green";

setTimeout(alert, 0, "Done");

Comment: Maybe it should work only with async function. (async () => { alert("Done"); })();

Answer (score 0):

beacuse the code is already done when u press the putton
if u need to make it run before changing color u can use
setTimeout(code, [delay]);
delay for num of mill seconds thah u need to wait before executing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).